# Iframe forces main document to scroll to top when zip code check runs

Tags: iframe, scroll

I have an iframe with scrolling disabled which loads into a login page. Customers can login and fill out a few forms. Whenever the customer types in a zip code the iframe runs a zip code check. The iframe then forces the main login page to scroll or "pop" to the top of the main login page.

Is there a way to keep the main document scroll without having to adjust the original iframed page code?

The iframe code is as follows:

```
<iframe src="https://combidata-apps.oranjeconcepts.com/registratie/allinhouse/registratie1.aspx?taal=nl" width="100%" height="750" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I do not have access to the source code of the iframe.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I posted the iframe code. as you can see I do not have access to the source of the iframe.